# MongoDB aggregation group by month in big collection - optimize pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I'm aware that this question has been asked before at SO - but I can't seem to find how to handle aggregation grouping in bigger collections. I have a set of +10 million records, and I just can't get any speed to it.

Running MongoDB v 3.2.

Having a field `__createDateUtc` (ISODate) in the schema, I'm trying the following pipeline:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            __createDateUtc: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            '_id': { $year: '$__createDateUtc' },
            'count': {$sum: 1},
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    },
])
```

This runs at +20 seconds. Could it be made faster? This is a fairly simple pipeline - so really - is there any other strategy that might help in this situation?

Comment: did you try without the `$project` stage ?

Comment: You have a limit with no sort.  I think you are only wanting the last 10 years of data but again - no sort.  Not sure how much data you have but you could filter by date first using $match so that only documents within the last 10 years are considered, thus the size of the dataset the aggregation is working on is reduced as early in the process as possible.

Comment: @barrypicker Yhey, sorry about that. Doesn't actually have 10 years of data, but since I'd like to be able to group also per month the limit is there as a proof of concept.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN removing `$project` makes no difference. The costly part here really is the date calculations...

Answer (score 1):

I did some bench marking with four different ways of getting the results that I wanted. The results are a discouraging.

Again, with a schema looking like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d665491fd5852755236a5dc"),
    ...
    "__createDateUtc" : ISODate("2019-08-28T10:16:49Z"),
    "__createDate" : {
        "year" : 2019,
        "month" : 8,
        "day" : 28,
        "yearMonth" : 201908,
        "yearMonthDay" : 20190829
    }
}
```

The results:

```
// Group by __createDate.yearMonth
db.transactions.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        '_id': '$__createDate.yearMonth',
        'count': {$sum: 1},
    } },
    { $limit: 10 },
    { $sort: {'_id': -1 } }
])
// 20 169 ms

// Group by year and month
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {$group: {
            '_id': {year: '$__createDate.year', month: '$__createDate.month' },
            'count': {$sum: 1},
    }},
    { $limit: 10 },
    { $sort: {'_id': -1 } }
])
// 23 777 ms

// Group by calculating year and month from ISODate
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {$group: {
            '_id': {year: { $year: '$__createDateUtc' }, month: { $month: '$__createDateUtc' } },
            'count': {$sum: 1},
    }},
    { $limit: 10 },
    { $sort: {'_id': -1 } }
])
// 16 444 ms

// Last stupid method to just run many queries with count
var years = [2017, 2018, 2019];
var results = {}
years.forEach(year => {
    results[year] = {};
    for(var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        var count = db.transactions.find({'__createDate.year': year, '__createDate.month': i}).count();
        if(count > 0) results[year][i] = count;
    }
})
// 10 701 ms
```

As you can see the last method of just running multiple counts is by far the fastest. Especially since I'm actually fetching a lot more data compared to the three other methods.

This just seems stupid to me. I know MongoDB is no search engine, but still. Aggregation is just not fast at all. Makes me wanna sync data to elastic search and try to aggregate within ES instead.